# Full HTML text not printing to console

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am doing some web scraping from the following address: https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201809060phi.htm

I want to print the HTML text to console so I can go read through it and find what I need. I have the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# assigning url
my_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201809060phi.htm'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
raw_page = uReq(my_url)
page_html = raw_page.read()
raw_page.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

print(page_soup)
```

Problem is that when I print this to the console I am not getting the full text. If you click the link you will see a section titled "Eagles Drives" about half way down the page. That is where the text starts that is printed to the console. Nothing above that point is being printed.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. Executing your code prints the full page html for me. Can you share your output?

Answer (score 0):

```
print(page_soup.prettify())
```

This will print html in a pretty format.